# Preventing Shiny selectInput from evaluating prematurely when updating a reactive plot

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am working on a Shiny app that generates various plots and allows users to change graphing parameters. For this, I'm using a combination of `selectInput`, `numericInput`, and `checkboxInput` functions **after** the plot is generated (`conditionalPanel`). I packaged the code so that the `data.frame` used for the graph is calculated reactively (to allow flexible subsetting before plotting). Everything works great, but when I want to update some graphing parameters (such as colors to use via `selectInput`), the code breaks down because it evaluates prematurely before I select all the necessary colors (i.e. when there are 4 colors needed, code breaks right after selecting the first color).

I know about `debounce` function to delay evaluation, but I don't want to use it because:

- I like the instant changes in the graph when I update other parameters
- Selection of colors can take some time, so it is difficult to set a predetermined delay time/time interval

One solution can be to add an `actionButton` shown conditionally (along with other graphing parameters) to regulate the firing of the reactive input values (see below). This is not ideal because after changing parameters, I need to click on update to renew the graph. Also, I'm not sure how this would even work because the `km_graph` is already a reactive plot object. Alternatively, is there a solution for regulating `selectInput` specifically so that until all the colors selected, it is not evaluated?

I read several posts on this issue but I couldn't find a solution that works with the design of my code. I will try to write sections of my `ui` and `server` to give an idea of what I'm trying to do:

### ui.R

```
# ...

 mainPanel(
                                  
                 plotOutput("km_graph"),
                 
                 # Conditional panel prompted only after the km_graph is generated             
                 conditionalPanel(
                     
                     condition = "output.km_graph" ,
                     
                     
                     checkboxInput("km_risk", label="Show risk table", F),
                     
                     selectInput("km_medline", label = "Mark median survival", 
                                 selected = "hv",
                                 choices = c("None" = "none",
                                             "Horizontal-Vertical" = "hv",
                                             "Vertical" = "v",
                                             "Horizontal" = "h")),
                     sliderInput("km_xlim", label="days", value = 6000, min = 10, max=10000),
                     selectInput("km_pal", "Select colors", multiple = T, 
                                 selectize = T, 
                                 selected = "jco",
                                 choices = list(`Pre-made palettes` = list("npg","aaas", "lancet", "jco", 
                                                                           "ucscgb", "UChicago", 
                                                                           "simpsons", "rickandmorty")
                                                 `Individual colors` = as.list(color_choices)) 
                                 )

# Need to find a way to prevent evaluating before all the colors are selected for km_pal

# Maybe another actionButton() here to update graph after all the parameters are selected?
```

### server.R

```
#...
# km_results() is the reactive object containing survival analysis results
# km_dat() is the reactive data frame used in the analyses

output$km_graph <- renderPlot({
                                      

        survminer::ggsurvplot(km_results(), data = km_dat(), 
                   pval = input$km_pval,
                   pval.method = input$km_pval,
                   risk.table = input$km_risk, 
                   conf.int = input$km_confint,
                   surv.median.line = input$km_medline,
                   break.time.by = input$km_breaktime,  
                   legend="right",
                   xlim=c(0, input$km_xlim),
                   palette = input$km_pal)     ###### This breaks due to premature evaluation
              
        
    })
```

## Full Reprex

```
    shinyApp(
        ui = basicPage(
            
            selectInput("dat", "Select data", 
                        selected = "iris", choices = c("iris")),
            
            actionButton("go", "Go!"),

            plotOutput("plot"),
            
            conditionalPanel(
                
                h3("graphing options"),
                
                condition = "output.plot",
                
                checkboxInput("plot_point", "Show points", T),
                
                selectizeInput("plot_colors", "Select colors", selected="jco",
                               choices = list(`premade`=list("jco", "npg"),
                                              `manual`=list("red", "black", "blue")))
                
            )
            
        ),
        
        server = function(input, output) {
            
            dat <- reactive({
                
                if(input$dat == "iris") iris
                
            })
            
           output$plot <- renderPlot({
               
               req(input$go)
            
            ggpubr::ggscatter(dat(), "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",
                              color="Species", palette=input$plot_colors)
                
            })
            
        }
    )
```

Thanks for the insights!

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Updated the post with reprex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I fully understood, but you could for example pass the `plot_colors` input in a reactive variable that is triggered by an action button "Apply colors" ?

(you need to add `multiple = TRUE` in the `selectizeInput`'s arguments)

Here is an example of code based on your reprex:

```r
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(

    selectInput("dat", "Select data", 
                selected = "iris", choices = c("iris")),

    actionButton("go", "Go!"),

    plotOutput("plot"),

    conditionalPanel(

      h3("graphing options"),

      condition = "output.plot",

      checkboxInput("plot_point", "Show points", T),

      selectizeInput("plot_colors", 
                     "Select colors", 
                     selected="jco",
                     multiple = TRUE,
                     choices = list(`premade`=list("jco", "npg"),
                                    `manual`=list("red", "black", "blue"))),

      actionButton(inputId = "apply", label = "Apply colors")

    )

  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    dat <- reactive({

      if(input$dat == "iris") iris

    })

    params_curve <- shiny::eventReactive(eventExpr = input$apply, 
                                         {
                                           return(list(colors = input$plot_colors))
                                         },
                                         ignoreNULL = F, 
                                         ignoreInit = F
    )

    output$plot <- renderPlot({

      req(input$go)

      ggpubr::ggscatter(dat(), "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",
                        color="Species", palette=params_curve()$colors)

    })



  }
)
```

If you select "red", "black", and "blue", then the dimension of your `plot_colors` variable is 3. So, the plot is rendered.

Comment: This seems to work with the reprex. I think I can adapt to the more complicated code I have. Thanks so much!